# MS Access 2010 Report Design Very slow

Tags: ms-access, vba, ms-access-2010

I have a MS Access 2010 DB with bunch of forms,queries ,macros, Reports etc

The data for my report comes from ODBC links to SQL Server 2000 Tables via linked table property.

Now, whenever i goto design mode of a report,Everything moves painfully slow (I have to wait atleast half a minute for every mouse click,or to select a text box , or any operation performed on the report)

The report itself takes about a minute to run.Which i dont mind.

All I am looking for, is a quicker way to make changes to the design of reports.

Answer (score 5, accepted):

This is an old question, but I had a similar issue with form design running extremely slowly recently. For me, only one form seemed to be affected (all others ran fine in design mode). The record source for the form was a complex query built on a hierarchy of subqueries. I dumped the query results into a table and used the table as the record source for the form instead of the query. This appears to have resolved the issue. Hope this helps someone else.

Answer (score 3):

I found the main cause to be the Access conversion program that converted 2003 format to 2010.  If you create a new .accdb and then import all of your object, it should work OK.  I definitely fixed my issues

Answer (score 2):

What worked for me is based on the answer provided by Albert Kallal at http://www.utteraccess.com/forum/lofiversion/index.php/t1959800.html.

For me, in my split database, if I open any table that is linked to the backend then opening any frontend form or subform was very quick.  If I do not have open and keep open a linked table, then it takes about 20 seconds to switch from Form View to Design View and another 20 seconds to open a subform, etc.  ***When I have a linked table open (it does not matter which table, just any table linked to the backend), then it takes about 1 second to do any of those functions.***  Huge difference!

Answer (score 1):

That is not normal. Something is wrong. Could be your Office/Access installation, your OS installation, something taking up too much of the system CPU, or your system just not having resources, like memory, to properly run Access. Or that your DB is corrupted and/or bloated.

Two tests you can try.
First, do a compact/repair on the DB and see if that fixes it.
Second, is to start your computer in Safe Mode and see if Access still runs slow. This will test for much of the above issues.

Comment: 1.I did the compact and repair but same result,I do compact and Repairs on DB every week 2.If i start my Computer in Safe mode can i still connect to Sql Server on Network?

Comment: Yes, if you allow safemode with networking. However, that won't be necessary to test the report design. You can design/modify your report without hitting the data. You just can't run the report.

Comment: One other test I thought of. Make a whole new DB with just 1 local table. Does the same thing still happen?

Comment: The Report Data is complicated with bunch of queries and tables joined to it,Its tough to replicate or copy all the server tables to local DB .I was looking for some setting that ties the Report Design and Data .i.e its understandable the report takes long time to run but why does it take so much time to respond to every action while in Design Mode? Its annoying!!

Comment: I didn't say copy or replicate all the table to local DB. I suggested a test of creating a new DB with just 1 local table, and nothing else. Then create a report off of it. Does it still run slow in design mode?

Comment: I tried the suggestions ,I guess it is just slow and I can't do much abt it!

Comment: If all my suggestions resulted in it still being slow, then I'd say your computer just doesn't have the power needed.

Answer (score 1):

What worked for me was to change the subdatasheet name from 'auto' to 'none' on all local tables. Do this in the property sheet in table design mode. There are routines posted elsewhere that will find all your local tables and change this value.

Answer (score 1):

A table was linked to an Excel file.  I found that when the Excel file was open, it took forever to change to design view on ANY form.  Closing the Excel file eliminated my problem!

Answer (score 1):

My case is access work fine in every function except opening or designing report. But access can work fine when network disconnect. I found it's cause by printer share by other computer and the computer which was removed. I remove the printer from control panel and access can work smoothly.

Comment: Thanks for adding your case, hope someone finds this helpful!